# Auto data-binding Java object without Spring MVC

Tags: java, data-binding, spring-mvc

I am developing a Java web project and not applying Spring MVC, Spring web-flow to it (because it is quite simple). I have a small problem when attaching value from HTTP request to Java object. Is there any standalone library or utility support us to bind data from client request to a server object automatically (matched by property name) without using Spring? Assume that parameters in client request had already built to a  map.
When I work with Grails (a web framework for Groovy), it has a very awesome way to fill data in request parameter to object by using: `object.properties=parameters`, but I do not know that in Java, do we have a similar mechanism to implement it?
Thank you so much.

Comment: I didn't understand your reason for not using Spring. In my opinion it is exactly the thing you want to use for something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Commons might help with [BeanUtilsBean](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html). It has cool methods like `getProperty()` and `setProperty()`, which might help if you wanna try to code it by hand using reflection. There's also the `populate(Object bean, Map properties)` method, which, i believe, is the closest to what you want.

[Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) is a java library specialized in mapping stuff from one structure to other. It might help.

[This guy](http://www.coderanch.com/t/512508/java/java/Fill-bean-data-HashMap-Reflection) posted a similar question on coderanch and, after some discussion, he came up with the following:

```
public static <T extends Object> T setFromMap(Class<T> beanClazz, HashMap<String, String> propValues) throws Exception  
{  
    T bean = (T) beanClazz.newInstance();  
    Object obj = new Object();  
    PropertyDescriptor[] pdescriptors = null;  
    BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(beanClazz);  
    pdescriptors = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();  
    for(int i=0; i<pdescriptors.length; i++)  
    {  
        String descriptorName = pdescriptors[i].getName();  
        if(!(descriptorName.equals("class")))  
        {  
            String propName = descriptorName;  
            String value = (String) propValues.get(propName);  
            if(value != null)  
            {  
                Object[] objArray = new Object[1];  
                objArray[0] = value;  
                Method writeMethod = pdescriptors[i].getWriteMethod();  
                writeMethod.invoke(bean, objArray);  
            }  
        }  
    }
    return bean;
}
```